# Symfony2: populating select list from a yaml file

Tags: forms, symfony, yaml

I have a multilingual movie site, and depending on locale, i want to have a dropdown select with the category of the movie.

i want to manage my categories in a yaml file (categories.yml), like this

```
category:
  {en: Movies,de: Filme }
  {en: Series,de: Serien }
  {en: Cartoons,de: Zeichentrick }
```

the category is an integer field, in the `Movie` Entity/Table

so i need to generate a select-dropdown like this

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Movies</option>
  <option value="2">Series</option>
  <option value="3">Cartoons</option>
</select>
```

ofcourse in the right locale-text

how do i generate the form-item from a yaml file? and for clean file management, where should it be put? under resources/languages? or under app/config?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a choice list.

First, update your form class so your field implements the `choice_list` with a new class you will create next:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form;

$builder
    ->add('myChoiceField', 'choice', array(
        'choice_list' => new \Acme\DemoBundle\Form\ChoiceList\DemoChoice(),
    ))
;
```

Next, implement `\Acme\DemoBundle\Form\ChoiceList\DemoChoice`:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\ChoiceList;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\SimpleChoiceList,
    Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList,
    Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;

class DemoChoice extends LazyChoiceList
{

    public function loadChoiceList ()
    {
        // read the Yaml file, $data will be an array
        $yaml = new Parser();
        $data = $yaml->parse(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config/data.yml'));

        // the keys of the array will be used as the option value
        // the values of the array will be used as the option text
        // ie: <option value="option-1">First Option</option>
        $choices = array(
            'option-1' => 'First Option',
            'option-2' => 'Second Option',
        );

        return new SimpleChoiceList($choices);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would better use one yml file per locale, just as translation files.
For example, in messages.en.yml:

```
category:
    movies: Movies
    series: Series
    cartoons: Cartoons
```